# Bisector of angle between lines

Tags: angle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwDzL.jpg)

**My attempt-**
(3x-6y-5)/3root(5)=(x+2y-11)/root(5)
this gives
3y=7

but both my answer and the correct answer are not matching as well as it says that it contains (1,-3) which when substituted in the correct answer does not satisfy it.

Comment: Where did you come across that question.

Comment: Online test series

Comment: Can you share the link please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two bisector lines are

- $x=\frac{19}3$
- $y=\frac{7}3$

and no one contains the point $(1,-3)$.

Comment: why they say (1,-3)

Comment: Maybe it’s just a typo.